AWS GraphQL Relational Subscriptions
I’m newer to AWS and looking to create a CRM with a dispatch schedule but I’m having a hard time setting up my subscriptions properly.
Here’s what my database structure looks like (not exact):
Jobs - clientID, description
Appointments - startTime, endTime, jobID
TechnicianLink - appointmentID, technicianID
If any of those update, I’d like to changes to reflect on my schedule in real time. My issue is, would it be better (or possible) to structure my graphQL file in a way where I only need one subscription, or should I create subscriptions for each: the jobs, appointments and technicianLink separately? Any advice would be great!
I’ve tried messing with the graphQL which pulls all the data I need with one query, but doesn’t work properly when the subscription runs
